# What should I put for "company domain" in Android Studio if I do not have a company?

Tags: android-studio, ide, google-play, publish, package-name

I'm beginning my first Android app. I want to make a simple photo sharing app. Will I need to create a company before publishing my app to Google Play? Is it possible to create, manage, own, and deal with issues without creating a company?

Comment: Many developers use a "code name" or their real name when developing apps on their own

Comment: I'm seeing the same recurring statement everywhere - that the company domain only matters if you are going to publish it to Google Play. Well, I am definitely planning on that. Is it possible to change this afterwards (but before publishing)?

Comment: I have not published to Google Play before, so I don't know the specifics, but I think it's required to identify your application and attach it to a developer/publisher. The fact that it's an actual "company" or not, doesn't matter. Lots of people write apps on their own, so their "company" is just their name, from a Google Play perspective. From what I understand, there's a publisher key or app key that is unique to every app you put on Google Play that is the real important piece, in that without it, you can't make updates to your app.

Comment: Related post - [Android Studio - Company Domain Name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30270936/465053),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your company domain will stay the same after publishing it, because if you change it, it will be known as a new app and the users won't receive the update. Technically, you won't need to create a company but ideally a company name is there so that it will be used in conjunction with the package ID. Make it unique because even if you do create a new app, it's better to stick with one company ID than another one.