# Android Studio - Company Domain Name

Tags: android, android-studio, android-applicationinfo

In Android Studio when you create a new project, you are prompted to put down a domain name.

I already know that you can make one up but what if you want to distribute your app on the Google Play store? Do I need to buy a web domain just to distribute my app even if I will never use my domain?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

No you don't need to buy a domain name to distribute your app. The domain name is used by Android Studio to generate a package name. Your package name is just a unique identifier for your application in the Google Play Store. It can be anything you want as long as it is unique. Generally, we use  reverse domain names like com.something. or org.something. structure for naming java packages. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html).

Comment: Recently I tried to publish an app in play store and I had to change my package name so that it does not start with com.example. Therefore package name cannot be anything.

Comment: It can be anything you want **as long as it is unique**.